# Creating a groupby column based on ids and category

Tags: python

I have a table below where i need to create a column of "Relevant" and "Non-Relevant" based on IDs.

The table looks like something below:

```
+----+--------------+--------+
| ID |  Experience  | Length |
+----+--------------+--------+
|  1 | Relevant     |      2 |
|  1 | Non-Relevant |      1 |
|  4 | Relevant     |      3 |
|  4 | Relevant     |      4 |
|  4 | Non-Relevant |      0 |
|  5 | Relevant     |      1 |
|  5 | Relevant     |      1 |
+----+--------------+--------+
```

This is the output I am trying to get

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| ID | Relevant | Non-Relevant |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 |        2 |            1 |
|  4 |        7 |            0 |
|  5 |        2 |            0 |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], 'exp': [x for x in 'rnrrnrr'], 'len':[2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1]})

pd.pivot_table(df, index='id', values='len', columns='exp', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Answer (score 1):

To create the dataframe:

```
ID = [1,1,4,4,4,5,5]
Experience = ['Relevant', 'Non-Relevant', 'Relevant', 'Relevant', 'Non-Relevant', 
'Relevant', 'Relevant']
length = [2,1,3,4,0,1,1]

dictionary = {'ID' : ID,
             'Experience' : Experience,
             'Length' : length}
```

To group it and then unstack:

```
df.groupby(by=['ID','Experience']).sum().unstack()['Length'].fillna(0)
```